# How to build WixV3 upgraded to WixV4 with custom boostrapper?

Tags: .net, wix, wix4

I am in the process of trying to learn custom UI's in Wix Burn but was finding most articles are written for WixV3.  As a fallback I decided I should try opening some WixV3 sample projects and update them to WixV4 to see if they run, but unfortunately I ran into an issue trying to build after upgrading...  I have updated my personal project that has no custom UI from Wixv3 to WixV4 but was hoping to add a custom UI.  However I figured I should learn what a sample project with a UI looks like in WixV4 first.

https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/CustomBurnUI

I took this sample project and updated the PackageGroupRef within the chain element to .net 4.8.1 since I updated the framework like the following.

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx481WebAsPrereq"/>
```

This allowed me to build, but upon running it appears I get an error and checking the logs indicate

> [7038:205C][2023-08-10T18:35:31]e000: Error 0x8007006e: Failed to load
> bootstrapper config file from path:
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp{3485F2C2-AAC7-43E0-8814-1FFCB005BD26}.ba\WixToolset.Mba.Host.config
> [7038:205C][2023-08-10T18:35:31]e000: Error 0x8007006e: Failed to find
> supported framework.

Googling the error doesn't yield much.  What exactly is the issue?  I assume it is somehow a missing dependency but is anybody able to provide more insight on how to resolve my issue?

In case the part of me updating the PackageGroupRef is incorrect, I also read this page... https://wixtoolset.org/docs/fourthree/faqs/#specifying-the-managed-ba-prerequisite but it does not provide much insight on how to specify prereqs for the MBA in Wix v4.

thank you for reading.